# Which is Adjective its Transfer or Transferred?

Tags: sentence-construction

What could be the Adjective in below sentence, I mean which is defining the date?

a) Your transfer date is 31-Dec-2020.

b) Your transferred date is 31-Dec-2020.

I can understand that most of the adjectives are in Past Participle format. but can we simple tense for adjective?

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage would be option a). The word date has no tense when used as a noun. Transfer, it’s adjective would remain the same as well in this case. The tricky part is that transfer, like many words, can be a noun or a verb. “A transfer” (noun) is not conjugated, “to transfer” (verb) would be conjugated. In your situation we are using it in it’s noun style.

For example:

He picked up a burned log.
Burn performed an action on the log, meaning it would be past participle.

In your case, transfer never performed an action on date, it only specified a type of date. This means you should treat it as a noun.

Adjective (same rules as noun in this case)

a) Your transfer date is 31-Dec-2020.

a) Your transfer date was 31-Dec-2019.

a) Your transfer date will be 31-Dec-2021.

Verb

a) I am transferring it on 31-Dec-2020.

a) I have transferred it on 31-Dec-2019.

a) I will transfer it on 31-Dec-2021.